# Conditionally add to a WHERE clause if a parameter is not null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure which accepts 3 parameters, can anyone advise what's the most efficient way to conditionally add to the where clause if a parameter is not null?

currently I have:

```
where ([LoggedIn] >= @dateFrom and [LoggedIn] <= @dateTo)
```

I would like to add to this if the parameter @email is not null, so conditionally doing the following

```
AND [Email] = @email
```

Thanks in advance, I hope that makes sense

Comment: I recommend [this series](https://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html); the TL;DR is [this section](https://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html#BasicStaticSQL).

Comment: AND `([Email] = @email OR @email IS NULL)` is how I would approach it.  I've done similar in the past.  Though, I can't comment on its efficiency compared to whatever other alternatives are out there.

Comment: Going with this option as it works and if faster than I expected, also email will never be null in the table

Comment: `AND [Email] = ISNULL(@email, [Email])` will also work then.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason why you cannot dynamically build an SQL that has parameters in, in your code and dynamically add values for the parameters as you extend the SQL text.. it looks something like:

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ([LoggedIn] >= @dateFrom and [LoggedIn] <= @dateTo)";

var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@dateFrom", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateFrom;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@dateTo", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateTo;


if(email != null){
  cmd.CommandText += " AND [Email] = @email";
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar, SIZE_OF_DB_COLUMN_HERE).Value = email;
}
```

You should, of course, choose your `SqlDbType` to match what is actually in your DB. If it's a `datetime2(7)` then it's a bit more wordy;

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@paramName", SqlDbType.DateTime2) { Scale = 7, Value = someVariable });
```

---

If you're doing your DB access with Dapper, just extend the SQL text and the parameters collection in a similar way

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ([LoggedIn] >= @dateFrom and [LoggedIn] <= @dateTo)";

var d = new Dictionary<string, object>(){
   { "@dateFrom", dateFrom },
   [ "@dateTo", dateTo }
};

if(email != null){
  sql += " AND [Email] = @email";
  d["@email"] = email;
}

var r = conn.Query<TypeOfObjectHere>(sql, d);
```

---

If you're doing this with EF, you can leverage the fact that you can call Where multiple times and it works like AND:

```
var q = context.Logins.Where(l =~> l.LoggedIn >= dateFrom && l.LoggedIn <= dateTo);

if(email != null)
  q = q.Where(l => l.Email == email);

var result = q.ToList();
```